# Run AVD and VirtualBox at the same time

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kvm

I'm developing for Android so I have the Android SDK installed and in it the program that runs virtual machine.

Also, from the same reason, I'm running a oracle virtual box to host myself a redmine server.

My host is linux mint.

Now the issue is, that whenever I'm trying to start one when the other is already on, it complains that the KVM is already taken.

I did not see it coming, and obviously it will be a real drag if I'll have to shut down my redmine box to every time I have to do testing, or have to shut down my testing AVD, every time I want to update progress on a task.

Is there a way I can run them both? It is not necessary for me to run both machines with hardware support.

Comment: So if you have Virtualbox started and then start some android emulator it still complains?

Comment: Yes, basically I can start one but not the other. The first one I start (either the AVD or VBOX) stays OK and does not even display an error if I try to start the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not have two kernel modules try to use the `vt-x` extension at once. So you can't have two hardware assisted virtual machines ran by two different hypervisors at the same time, on the same node.

However, you can remove the module that is currently using the extension via `modprobe`(and friends). This would free up the extension for use by the other hypervisor.

For `kvm` the modules you would need to remove are: `kvm`, `kvm_intel` or `kvm_amd`. then `virtualbox` would be allowed to use `vt-x`.

The same goes for whatever modules `virtualbox` inserts into the kernel.

---

You can use `qemu`(the userland tool commonly paired with `kvm`) with software emulation. it does that by default when you don't specify `-machine accel=kvm` or `-enable-kvm` and you will have a virtual machine without hardware assisted acceleration.

I am not very familiar with `virtualbox` so i am not sure of your options with it, for non-accelerated virtual machines.

Comment: Good answer. I ended up doing something that is only slightly different. I started the AVD from the command line tool with `./emulator -avd AVD-GalaxyS3 -qemu -disable-kvm` (apparently the default behaviour for AVD is -enable-kvm). The AVD is now incredibly slow, but that was expected.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
I finally figured out that the AVD runs on KVM.  So one option would be to switch your hypervisor to KVM.  I did it six months ago to support GPU passthrough and haven't looked back.

ORIGINAL:
For others coming along later, [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/download/) lets you run an Android x86 image in another VirtualBox VM -- so obviously there's no conflict running alongside your existing VM.

Genymotion is commercial software, but does have a free-beer version for hobbyists.  Just create an account!

**NOTE:** in order to use the free capabilities, it's available in the 'fun-zone', where it states you're able to use it for personal use, https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/.

It still requires that you create an account.